# Are there any penetration test tools available for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Basically the title. I was looking around but I couldn't find any resources for penetration testing on GCP. Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2):

Google recently release a web-app vulnerability scanner for its Google Cloud platform : https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/